# Python: Why doesn't [0,1,2][-1:1] raise an error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, slice

In Python one can use array slice notation to get a subset of values in an iterable:

```
a = [0,1,2]
a[0:2]
# returns all members from the 0th to the 2nd: [0,1]
```

If you attempt to extract a slice where the first value is negative, and the second value is positive, however, the request returns an empty list:

```
a[-1:2]
# returns []
```

This is counterintuitive to me, as the range defined by -1:2 seems to be a *superset* of the range defined by 0:2.

I know one can use negative indexes to pluck from the end of an array with Python slice notation (ex: `a[-1]` is 2), but it seems like a negative value in the first slice position and a positive in the second should either raise an error or return a superset of the values returned by the same slice with a 0 in first position.

I'd be curious to know the motivation behind the empty list returned by slice requests with a negative value in the first position with a positive value in the second if anyone happens to have insight on this front...

Comment: `a[-1:2]` reads as `a[len(a)-1:2]`

Comment: I hear that. But if the value returned by a slice with a negative value in first position is always empty, why doesn't the language raise an error? There doesn't seem to be a legitimate use case for a negative value in the first position of a slice function, so it seems like developers should be warned if this situation arises...

Comment: @Kos i think its more accurate to say that `a[-1:2]` reads as `a[-1%len(a): 2]` because you can put a -7 in there with no problems

Comment: @duhaime how about "give me 3 last elements of this list"?

Comment: What do you mean a *superset*? What would the superset of `a[-1,2]` look like? And sure there are use-cases where a negative value in the first position is handy, for example, sometimes your logic will be "I want the slice that starts 5 elements from the end and stops at the fourth element", so `[1,2,3,4,5,6][-5: 3]` which will give `[2, 3]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Negative indices are very useful to get the last elements :

```
>>> letters = list('abcdefgh')
>>> letters[-3:]
['f', 'g', 'h']
>>> letters[-3:-1]
['f', 'g']
```

It would be a huge mistake to prematurely raise an exception in this case.

You can also mix negative and positive indices :

```
>>> letters[-5:6]
['d', 'e', 'f']
```

Which means elements after the 5th last element and before the 6th element.

In your case :

```
>>> letters[-1:2]
[]
```

Returns an empty list because there's no element between the last and the second one.

It isn't always empty, though :

```
>>> ['a'][-1:2]
['a']
>>> ['a','b'][-1:2]
['b']
```

Comment: Ah, you're right, I'm not thinking. My real question is: Is there a use case for a slice with a negative in first position and positive in second position?

Comment: This clears it up perfectly. I see the use case now--thank ye!

Answer (score 3):

I think it's just a misunderstanding: negative values are interpreted as "counting from the end", so `[-1:2]` is not a superset of `[0:2]`. It's the other way around! Because whatever `-1` is (the actual value depends on the length of the iterable) it will always be `>= 0`.

In your case you have a length 3 array so `-1` is interpreted as `2` and you want to get the items between 2 and 2 (stop exclusive) so you get an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want a slice of the last 10 elements. This is easily done with `a[-10:]`. If that would raise a error, you would have write something unpleasant like `a[len(a)-10:]`. And even worse, if `a` is not a variable with a list you used before but something you calculated right now, you would need to create a new variable just to have a possibility to take length. And you don't if you can just write `[-10:]` at the end.

Obviously, this can have drawbacks when this is not intended behaviour, but for the sake of conciseness in other cases this probably worth it.